# how to json parse a python output and store its values like in dict or variables?

Tags: python, json, loops, subprocess, jsonparser

I have a python code that outputs json

```
import json 
from faker import Faker
import random
from random import randint
import subprocess
fake = Faker('en_US')

for _ in range(1):
sms =  {
        "name": fake.name(),
        "email": fake.email(),          
        "location": "usa"
        }

with open('abc.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(sms, outfile)

print(sms)
```

subprocess:

```
x=subprocess.Popen([" python"," first.py"],shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = x.communicate()
print(output)
```

output I am getting :

```
(b'{\n  "name": "elmoroy",\n  "email":"ssbyt@gmail.com"}\n', None)
```

output I need :

```
{
"name": "elmoroy",
"email":"ssbyt@gmail.com
}
```

If I call `output["name"]`  it should return `elmoroy`.

Comment: The `first.py` isn't outputting anything to `stdout`, so `x` will be nothing. The script creates a file `abc.json`, so you can open a read that file when the subprocess is finished. Alternatively, you could `print(json.dumps(sms))` and write some output to `stdout`.

Comment: updated pl check

Comment: `print(sms)` would _not_ produce the output you say you're getting.

Comment: `x=subprocess.Popen([" python"," first.py"],shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = x.communicate()
print(output)`     if you run this youll get it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

communicate() returns a tuple (stdout_data, stderr_data), the output you need is in `output[0]` which is a string representation of the dictionary you need, you can then use `my_dict = json.loads(output[0])` to get a dictionary.

UPDATE : to run this in a loop

```
my_dict = {}
for i in range(20):
    x=subprocess.Popen([" python"," first.py"],shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = x.communicate()
    my_dict.update({i: json.loads(output[0])})
```

`my_dict` would hold 20 dictionaries of the printed `sms` variable

Comment: how to store if i loop the code for 20 times ? if i loop it for 20 times and i need to store all the output generated.

Comment: According to your code, looping for 20 times would still print 1 sms variable with 1 dictionary in it, or have I not understood your question?

Comment: i need to loop this `x=subprocess.Popen([" python"," first.py"],shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = x.communicate()
print(output)`  for 20 times and store all the outputs in dicts

Comment: `my_iter_dict = {i: json.loads(subprocess.Popen([" python"," first.py"],shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]) for i in range(20)}` alternatively, inside a for loop (with an existing dict var name `my_dict` you could do `my_dict.update({i: json.loads(output[0])})` I'm using the iteration number as keys, you could use whatever u'd like

Comment: changed `my_dict ` to `my_iter_dict`  getting `i` is not defined

Comment: `i` is the loop's index, i'll edit my answer so it would make more sense

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using `json.load`, like this:

```
with open('abc.json') as in_file:
    obj = json.load(in_file)
print(obj)
```

Refer to 'Decoding JSON' in [json — JSON encoder and decoder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

---edit---

Try this:

First, you get a file like:

```py
import json

for _ in range(1):
    sms =  {
            "name": 'some name',
            "email": 'some email',
            "location": "usa"
    }


with open('abc.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(sms, outfile)
```

Then, you get another file like:

```py
import json

with open('abc.json') as in_file:
    sms = json.load(in_file)
print(sms)
```

Execute first file and then the second, and you can see the second file parse the file content into a json object.

Comment: i wont work, u didnt mentioned sms in load as i have the data that should be printed

Comment: I provide more detail in my answer. Maybe you can have another try.

Comment: i dont want to save the output into a another file, i need to load from print function and use it for later

Comment: If you want to load json from string, you can try `json.loads`. For example, `json.loads('{"key": "value"}')` will get you an json object.

Comment: i need to capture data from print(output) and store them in a dict